# DNS problem, whois shows new servers, dig and soa nslookup show old older dns

Tags: dns, nslookup

I recently began migrating an old site to Drupal, and the hosting service I was using was really cheap and wouldn't have worked with all the modules I installed. I already hired a hosting account at a new (Drupal friendly) service and changed my DNS settings to point to their servers,... but the problem is that it's been a couple of days and the domain still points to the old account. When I whois my domain I can see in the domain servers section that the new servers show up, but if I nslookup or dig the domain I find the older servers. How could this be?

Comment: Does a nslookup from any connection show the old result or is it only from a specific location? It could be that your have a long-standing DNS cache that needs to be flushed. Have you tried using a different DNS server to resolve the location (like google 8.8.8.8)?

Comment: @Quintin Robinson I haven't tried from a different connection, is there an online tool to check what it looks like from a different ip?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are few possible reasons:

- Your ISP is still resolving you domain name to the old servers
- You have a local DNS server with a long TTL
- You have a record in your host file pointing to the old server
- The DNS change wasn't done correctly

Comment: I just checked from http://networking.ringofsaturn.com/Tools/dig.php and the dns resolves correctly, I guess it's a local problem then

Comment: did you find the problem was I close?